# Bim 360 Location

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I notice that Autodesk has a private beta that includes an endpoint to get Locations. My company are approved Autodesk developers and wish to know if and how they can gain access to this endpoint?

```
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360-private/v1/reference/http/locations-list-nodes-GET/
```

If they can't gain access to this endpoint they would like to know the approximate date that this endpoint will become public as it looks highly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instruction here to contact the corresponding team to get private-beta access:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360-private/v1/overview/#locations